# Setting lower and upper limits to classes in kriging interpolation, ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, interpolation, classification, kriging

I am using the kriging interpolation tool. I included two dummy values within my dataset:- an upper limit and a lower limit.

I ran the tool in arc map 10.1 software. However, I want to change the upper and lower limits of the kriging interpolation classes to the limits I set in the dataset. I will then   manually classify the kriging interpolation into specific classes.

How do I set the upper and lower limits for the interpolated classes?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean to reclassify the data into categories based on specific ranges, thus creating a discrete raster from a continuous raster. Do this...

Since you already have the Spatial Analyst extension, go to Spatial Analyst in your toolbox. Click on Reclass, then Reclassify. Here you can add specific ranges and map them each to a new value, then export to a new raster.